# Format time month to Capital letter

Tags: go, time

I want to format time to

> 2006/JAN/hello02JAN2006file.csv.zip

It contains month name in Capital letter,

say `downloadDate` is `time.Time`

`downloadDate.Format("2006/JAN/hello02JAN2006file.csv.zip")` won't convert `JAN` to Month name, as it won't parse JAN, it will need `Jan` ,If I give it `Jan` , then month name will also be like this ( `Apr`, `May`, ...) while I need `APR` or `MAY`

my solution to work around here is to replace JAN by using [strings.Replace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) method

```
strings.Replace(downloadDate.Format("2006/JAN/hello02JAN2006file.csv.zip"), "JAN", strings.ToUpper(downloadDate.Format("Jan")), -1)
```

am I missing something in [time.Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) doc, or above is the only way to accomplish this ?

Comment: I believe you're not missing anything in the doc, the matching of months in the layout is case sensitive, and your solution seems valid to me.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/format.go#L154-L162

Comment: yeah, I know, it is quite unfortunate for go that we can't use date modifiers, which are much more powerful, or is it there any advantage of using layout